# PdfKit headers with --html-header don't show on generated pdf

Tags: python, flask, pdf-generation, pdfkit

Hello I am making an application in Flask and I want to have an endpoint that returns a PDF that should contain a header and footer on every page. I am using PDFKIT and generating the pdf from HTML templates. At this point, I can get the PDF as response but it comes without headers.

At this point my controller looks like this:

```
@app.route('/pdf_generator/')
def get_pdf_report():
    this_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    html_string = render_template('template.html', image_path='file://' + os.path.join(this_folder))

    options = {
        "enable-local-file-access": ""
    }

    try:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html', delete=False) as header_html:
            options['--header-html'] = header_html.name
            header_html.write(render_template('header.html', image_path='file://' + os.path.join(this_folder)).encode('utf-8'))
            header_html.flush()

        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html_string, options=options)
        response = make_response(pdf)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        filename = 'pdf-from-html.pdf'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = ('attachment; filename=' + filename)
        return response  # returns the response.

    finally:
        # Ensure temporary file is deleted after finishing work
        os.remove(options['--header-html'])
```

My header.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    Code of your test goes here.

</body>
</html>
```

And my template.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    Code of your header goes here.

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?